# How to convert config.properties into key value pairs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, property-files

I am trying to convert a java properties file into a key value pairs that I can use in jquery. The property file sends information that looks like this:

```
company1=Google
company2=eBay
company3=Yahoo
```

And I want it in this form:

```
var obj = {
 company1: Google,
 company2: ebay,
 company3: Yahoo
};
```

I am going to be accessing the property file through a URL.

Comment: javascript & java is different.

Comment: yes I know. But I am trying to convert the output from the property file into key-value pairs. What I get is the top example and I need to convert to the bottom example.

Comment: You can always use this reference when constructing a json : https://www.json.org/

Comment: how does your output look like and are you getting the output in a javascript variable

Comment: Do you need to do this programatically at runtime? As in your program reading the properties file and generating a Javascript object based on it?

Comment: if you use maven you can get a json library https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json

Comment: Yes, exactly.  I need to do it programmatically at runtime. @AndreiPietrusel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your file comes exactly the way you've pasted it here, I would approach it something like this:

```js
var data = "company1=Google\ncompany2=eBay\ncompany3=Yahoo";

var formattedData = data
  // split the data by line
  .split("\n")
  // split each row into key and property
  .map(row => row.split("="))
  // use reduce to assign key-value pairs to a new object
  // using Array.prototype.reduce
  .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => (acc[key] = value, acc), {});

var obj = formattedData;

console.log(obj);
```

This post may be helpful if you need to support ES5 [Create object from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42974735/create-object-from-array)

Comment: Good answer +1. Note that your reduce could be rewritten as `.reduce((acc, [key, value]) => (acc[key] = value, acc), {});` which is both shorter and faster since it doesn't re-allocate the accumulator each step through the loop.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Just use npm module https://www.npmjs.com/package/properties

This module implements the Java .properties specification and adds additional features like ini sections, variables (key referencing), namespaces, importing files and much more.

```
# file
compa = 1
compb = 2


nodejs:

var properties = require ("properties");

properties.parse ("file.properties", { path: true }, function (error, obj){
  if (error) return console.error (error);

  console.log (obj);
  //{ compa : 1, compb : 2 }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. However for this project I was hoping for something to just parse the data. Completely done in the front end

Comment: While it's frequently a good idea to use battle-tested third party libraries instead of rolling your own, for something this trivial it probably isn't worth taking on a dependency (insert left-pad joke here) :)