# how to setState all element of list of states

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have an array of string names and i want to do bellow

```
  let accountcode:{a:1,b:2};
    let array=["first","second",third];
    this.setState({[array[0]:accountCode,array[1]:accountCode,array[3]:accountCode]})
```

but array is dynamic list and i should map in array and setState every item of it in one setState
i try

```
 object.setState(
        {...stateName:accountCodes}
      )
```

but not working and i also try below and not throw syntax error:

```
 object.setState(
        stateName.map(s=>{[s]=accountCodes})
      )
```

what should  i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function to achieve it. Each iteration in your array will add the element to your object with a computed property :

```
const accountcode = { a: 1, b: 2 };
const array = ["first","second","third"];
this.setState(array.reduce((acc, val) => ({[val]: accountcode, ...acc}), {}));
```

Working example :

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        const accountcode = { a: 1, b: 2 };
        const array = ["first", "second", "third"];
        this.setState(array.reduce((acc, val) => ({ [val]: accountcode, ...acc }), {}));
    }

    render(){
        console.log(this.state)
        return <div></div>
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.5.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.5.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at creating an object from an array. The question is just a rephrase of [creating an object from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42974735/create-object-from-array).

In your case, the solution may be as follows:

```
let accountCode = {a: 1, b: 2};
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4];

let output = {};
for (let key of array) {
    output[key] = accountCode;
}

// Almost forgot this
this.setState(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write something like this:

```
let accountCode = {a:1, b:2};
let array = ["first", "second", "third"];

/* Function in which you will call setState */
let newState = {};
array.forEach(el => {
  newState[el] = accountCode;
});
```

Though, I suggest you to not simply write `newState[el] = accountCode;` otherwise you are using the same Object for each property of `newState`. You could write `newState[el] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(accountCode));` to prevent that!