# Creating a Object Array From an Array

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this:

```
const companyNames = ["A", "B", "C"];
```

I want to convert it to a something like this:

```
const companyNames = {
  0: 'A',
  1: 'B',
  2: 'C'
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create object from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42974735/create-object-from-array)

Comment: Yes it is, sorry for reasking it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Spread Operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
{ ...["A", "B", "C"] }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forEach`:

```js
var companyNames = ["A", "B", "C"];
var data = {};
companyNames.forEach(function(value, index) {
  data[index] = value;
})
console.log(data)
```