# Create object with list of keys

Tags: javascript

What is the concisest way to create an object from a list of keys, all set to the same value. For example,

```
const keys = [1, 2, 3, 4]
const value = 0
```

What is the tersest way to attain the object

```
{
  “1”: 0,
  “2”: 0,
  “3”: 0,
  “4”: 0
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create object from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42974735/create-object-from-array)

Answer (score 7):

You can use [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

```js
const keys = [1, 2, 3, 4]
const value = 0

const result = Object.fromEntries(keys.map(k => [k, value]))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Maybe make it clearer in an explanation or something that you're presenting two possible methods and what the advantages/disadvantages of each are.

Comment: Beware the [reduce-spread](https://www.richsnapp.com/article/2019/06-09-reduce-spread-anti-pattern) antipattern.

Answer (score 5):

Should probably be something among:

```js
const keys = [1, 2, 3 ,4];
const value = 0;

console.log(
  keys.reduce((acc, key) => (acc[key] = value, acc), {})
);
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way I can think of would be to use `.reduce()`;

```js
const keys = [1, 2, 3, 4]
const value = 0

const obj = keys.reduce((carry, item) => {
    carry[item] = value;
    return carry;
}, {});

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Beware the [reduce-spread](https://www.richsnapp.com/article/2019/06-09-reduce-spread-anti-pattern) antipattern.

Comment: @MoritzRoessler good point :) just realized I did this mistake several times until now :|