# Convert array of strings to object with params and values

Tags: javascript

I have next array with strings:

```
['val1=123','val2=456']
```

How I can split it to object with params and values?

```
{
  val1: 123,
  val2: 456,
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) with [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and/or [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)?

Comment: res.map(x => x.split('=')); returns me arrays

Comment: There are dozens of duplicates. What are you struggling with? This is pretty similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42974735/create-object-from-array#42974762

Comment: @Ted save that output to a variable `res2` or similar. Then you can use `Object.fromEntries(res2)`

Comment: const res = ['val1=123','val2=456'];
res.map(x => x.split('='));
result: [
  [
    "val1",
    "123"
  ],
  [
    "vall2",
    "456"
  ],

Comment: @Ted please do not post code in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

```js
const recordStrings = ['val1=123', 'val2=456']
const record = Object.fromEntries(
  recordStrings.map(str => str.split('='))
)

console.log(record)
```

Explanation:

`recordStrings.map(str => str.split('='))` returns `[[val1, 123], [val2, 456]]`.

`Object.fromEntries(entries)` creates an object from an array containing `[key, value]` tuples.

Comment: `Object.fromEntries` that's amazing

Answer (score 2):

You can try with ***reduce*** method, it's really helpful to convert an array to any others data type like an object, string, number.

```js
const arr = ['val1=123','val2=456'];

const items = arr.reduce((total, item) => {
  const [key, value] = item.split('=');
  if (key) {
    total[key] = value
  }
  return total;
}, {})

console.log(items);
```

Comment: `Array#reduce` is very powerful, which is why it is poor at communicating intent. I would recommend a combination of `Array#map` and `Object.fromEntries` for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arr = ['val1=123', 'val2=456']
let object = {}

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var split = arr[i].split("=")
  object[split[0]] = split[1]
}

console.log(object); // { val1: '123', val2: '456' }
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let obj = {};
let arr = ['val1=123', 'val2=456'];

arr.forEach(i => {
  let x = i.split('=');
  obj[x[0]] = parseInt(x[1]);
});

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the strings in the array and convert the array to an object:

```js
const res = ['val1=123','val2=456'];
const result = Object.fromEntries(res.map(x => {
    const [l, r] = x.split('=');
    return [l, +r];
}));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: `Object.fromEntries` that's amazing

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = ['val1=123','val2=456'];
    arr.forEach(str => {
        let arrStr = str.split('=');
        eval(arrStr[0] + '= ' + arrStr[1] + ';');
    })
    console.log(val1, val2);
```

OR

```js
let arr = ['val1=123','val2=456'];
    arr.forEach(str => {
        let arrStr = str.split('=');
        window[arrStr[0]] = arrStr[1];
    })
    console.log(val1, val2);
```